# Difference between "World" and "Universe"

Tags: meaning

What are the differences between the two? I thought that "World" means everything, i.e the same as "Universe" (disclaimer: I'm not making a statement about multiverses here, don't take it as a scientific text). But people seem to think it means the same as "Earth".

Comment: While we're on the topic, is anyone else annoyed by the recent prevalence of "Earth" being used instead of "world"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am with the people.

To me as well, World = Earth while the Universe = earth and space including the great unknown.

The [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0960520#m_en_gb0960520) seems to agree.

Origin of World:
Old English *w(e)oruld*, from a Germanic compound meaning 'age of man'; related to Dutch *wereld* and German *Welt*.

Origin of Universe:
late Middle English: from Old French *univers* or Latin *universum*, neuter of *universus* 'combined into one, whole', from *uni-* 'one' + *versus* 'turned' (past participle of *vertere*).

Comment: World != Earth.  World is more closely equal to planet. For example if you lived on Mars, using world would no longer refer to Earth but to Mars.

Comment: @Tester101 Earth is *The World* (e.g. *Times Atlas of the World*). Mars is *a world*.

Comment: @Tester101: Instinctively, I'd assume that if we colonized Mars, "the world" would be inclusive of both. I kind of assume it means "everything", but limited to what's practical (where we live, what we occupy ourselves with). Not a distant star that doesn't impact us in any way. Currently, "the world" equals "Earth" because it's currently the only thing we're occupying. Just like how we e.g. say "you are my world" meaning "you are my everything". ALso, I'm distinguishing between "a world" and "*the* world" here.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the difference depends on context. The most literal senses of *world* versus *universe* are, respectively, the planet Earth versus all that exists. However, for practical purposes, it is often clear that all instances of a thing that could possibly exist must exist on our planet, so that the difference becomes irrelevant.

> You are the most beautiful man in the
>   world.

Since there are hardly any men outside Earth, the words *world* and *universe* could be used interchangeably here.

> This must be the highest mountain in
>   the universe.

Since there are mountains on Mars, you could not substitute *world* here.

In many expressions where it doesn't matter, the word *world* is used because it is the more common word.

Answer (score 3):

World generally means Earth, as InSane mentioned.

Sometimes, however, it is used in a more general sense. See definitions 7-9 in this [dictionary entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/world). Also, consider the [many-worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) interpretation of quantum mechanics (also known as many-universes) and the notion of [possible world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possible_world) in philosophy and logic.

I speculate that "world" is often seen as an acceptable substitute for "universe" (even though it's a less common meaning) for reasons of convenience: "world" is two syllables shorter.

Comment: +1 I think the two are used in a figurative sense to mean all-encompassing. *Universe* will also be used to trump *world* the way fortissimo trumps forte.

Answer (score 0):

*Universe* means *all existing matter and space considered as a whole*; it is also used with the meaning of *a particular sphere of activity, interest, or experience*.

> The front parlor was the hub of her universe.

*World* means:

- (usually *the world*) the earth, together with all of its countries, peoples, and natural features.
- (*the world*) all of the people, societies, and institutions on the earth.
- [as adjective] denoting one of the most important or influential people or things of its class.
- another planet like the earth.
- the material universe or all that exists; everything.

> He was doing his bit to save the world.
>   They had been brought up to regard France as a world power.
>   Scientists are verifying the possibility of life on other worlds.

Comment: Can you give an example of the last usage? (material universe)

Comment: I've often applied the meaning of "a particular sphere of activity, interest, or experience" to "world." I'm not the only person to do this, surely?

Answer (score 0):

*Universe* is unambiguous.  It only ever means all that exists.  *World* can have all of the meanings stated in previous answers to the question.

Answer (score -2):

When we see a "World" map, it is a map of the earth. Not wanting to get into religion, but the bible says, "For God so loved the world.....", and based upon the "world map" theory, that would mean that God loved earth, and the rest of the planets aren't considered. I assume the universe takes in all of the planets, so I also assume the universe is larger than the world (earth). But.....infinity comes into play, and does the universe have borders.....?? Are there other planets, or other "X's" that we don't know about, or understand? If so, how and when were they created? Many unknowns.....but we, as earthlings, want to think we know, either through science or religion, or a combination. Does anyone know?

Comment: "Not wanting to get into religion, but the bible says.." haha. Thanks for the answer. But I love such statements. "I don't want to, but ...somehow I feel forced to"